# Purpose of redux-cli

Tags: reactjs, redux

currently looking through a boilerplate called [react-redux-start-kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit) by Dave Zuko, and there is a folder called `blueprints`. Apparently it is for a library called `redux-cli`, and having no clue what that is I did some research. ([Link](https://github.com/SpencerCDixon/redux-cli) to `redux-cli`)

The problem is, the documentation for `redux-cli` didn't really say what it is. I have also read that `redux-cli` makes it faster to build apps. Could someone please explain to me what `redux-cli` is, and how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[redux-cli](https://github.com/SpencerCDixon/redux-cli) is a utility that speeds up development by reducing work required to create basic elements of your app, e.g. components. Usually, when you create such component, you have to create file for a component, test suite and they all start with a certain structure that you usually copy / paste from other, existing components. With redux-cli you just use simplified commands in your console to auto-generate those basic versions of a new component and you can just jump in and start writing the essence of it.

`blueprints` are simply templates, redux-cli uses when running commands (for example when running command to create new component it will look at blueprints directory first and see if you have customized template for how you want your components to be initialized). Documentation is pretty clear I'd say - https://github.com/SpencerCDixon/redux-cli#creating-blueprints

Comment: Hello, very detailed thank you! With `redux-cli` are the dependencies actually added to the main app's json file?

Comment: If you use `blueprints`, `redux-cli` will just generate new component / route. You need to add it yourself to appropriate place in your app.